# Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto: error while using peer command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am working on Hyperledger fabric 2.3 and I got this error whenever I try to use peer command.
and followed the steps are as follows: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html#package-the-smart-contract So that I can use peer command outside the CLI.

**Error: ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, specified path "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/config/msp" does not exist or cannot be accessed: stat /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/config/msp: no such file or directory**

bash#  export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH

bash#  peer version

peer:

Version: 2.3.1

Commit SHA: 2f69b4222

Go version: go1.14.12

OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Chaincode:

Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric

Docker Namespace: hyperledger

bash# peer channel list

2021-03-16 08:12:25.954 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, specified path "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/config/msp" does not exist or cannot be accessed: stat /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/config/msp: no such file or directory

[image]

Please do tell me what is the meaning of this error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the `CORE_PEER_MSCONFIGPATH` variable:

```bash
echo $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
```

If you have set this environment variable, you can get output at this path:

```
/home/www/byfn-on-k8s/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
```

which is the path of your `msp`.

then you can check msp dir in this path is correct or not.

[image: Terminal Text]

If there is no output, you may not have set the `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Run these three commands:

```bash
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp

export
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
```